# PyCharm cannot find existing Matplotlib installation or install new one

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, matplotlib, pip, pycharm

I am trying to run and debug Python scripts with PyCharm that use Matplotlib plots. However I can't do either because PyCharm can't find my existing Matplotlib installation, and fails to download and install it's own version when I try to install Matplotlib through the settings/package manager interface.

However, I already have Matplotlib installed on my computer, and when I run the script through terminal, everything works just fine.

So my question is, how can I either:

1. Successfully install Matplotlib through PyCharm or
2. Direct PyCharm to my existing Matplotlib installation

### System versions

- **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04
- **Python:** 3.7.0 (3.4 also installed)
- **Pip:** 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
- **Pip3:** 18.1 from /home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
- **Matplotlib:** 3.0.2
- **PyCharm:** PyCharm community v 2018.3.1
- **PyCharm interpreter:** Python 3.7

### Error when installing Matplotlib through PyCharm

```
Collecting matplotlib==3.0.2
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/matplotlib/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.0.2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.0.2
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't include OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher, which is now required by Python 3.7. This means the ssl module of python will not be built in. Without the ssl module pip is unable to download packages from the repositories.

If you [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) pycharms to use your system version of python (3.4) which is what will be used by the terminal you should be fine to get matplotlib.

My recommendation would be to upgrade to 16.04 or later.

Comment: That worked. Of course, because it is Python3.4 the latest version of matplotlib that PyCharm can install is 2.2.3, but that's better than nothing.